# Como resolver o problema Call to a member function diff() on string in

Tags: php

Estou encontrando uma falha quando tento comparar uma data que está na base de dados com a data atual, me retorna a falha Call to a member function diff() on string in

Pego a data do banco de dados e quando dou um echo aparece correto.

```
$dbDate = $this->Query->fetchColumn();
```

Quando tento gerar a data atual para posterior comparação gera a falha.

```
$aDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

O log da falha gerada no servidor aponta para a linha abaixo, quando tenta verificar a defirença.

```
$timePassed = $dbDate->diff($aDate);
```

Eu preciso saber quantos minutos passaram desde a data que está no banco de dados.

```
$minutes  = $timePassed->days * 24 * 60;
$minutes += $timePassed->h * 60;
$minutes += $timePassed->i;
```

Comment: Pelo aspeto `$dbDate` provavelmente será uma string. Algo que pode confirmar fazendo `var_dump($dbDate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É preciso converter o `$aDate` em objeto `DateTime`:

```
$aDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Bem como a data vinda do banco:

```
$dbDate = new DateTime($dbDate);
```

Ficando assim:

```
$dbDate = new DateTime($dbDate);
$aDate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$timePassed = $dbDate->diff($aDate);
$minutes  = $timePassed->days * 24 * 60;
$minutes += $timePassed->h * 60;
$minutes += $timePassed->i;
```

**[Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Lc47iU#stdin)**

Comment: Fiz as mudanças e funcionou.. Grato!!

Comment: REsolveu meu problema também, 4 anos depois, obrigado! =)